# Hangfire Job is not removed after ExpireAt

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, hangfire

I am using the default `SQL Server` storage for `Hangfire`. Since the rate of job creation per-day can be quite high (in the count of hundreds of thousands), the size of the database also grows quite fast.

Initially I thought it will still be fine because `Succeeded` jobs would be removed after one day. To my surprise, even after several days, the job is not yet removed from `Hangfire.Jobs` table.

When I ran this query on 30 July 2015:

```
select min(ExpireAt) from Hangfire.Job
where StateName = 'Succeeded'
```

I got `2015-07-21 13:28:27.543`, which is about 9 days ago.

I can manually delete the jobs myself or create a batch job that would periodically clean it up, but is there any scenario where the Succeeded job are still retained beyond their ExpireAt?

Comment: This issue seems to be specific to hangfire and not SQL Azure or SQL Server. Have you tried asking the Hangfire forum at http://discuss.hangfire.io/ ?

Comment: yes, I did. no response so far though

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is addressed in the newer version of Hangfire, but since then we have switched to using Hangfire Pro with Redis storage version 2.0.x. No such issue in this version